# Can Stack Overflow users post examples instead of questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions

I was wondering if users would be penalised in any way for posting examples instead of questions?

Is this site for questions only?

Comment: If you think you have examples that could help people and answer questions that haven't been asked, you could ask a question, and then post your own answer.

Comment: It took me a minute to understand this, but I think you're asking if it's ok to ask a question you think others may have, and include the answer in the question itself. This is part of the FAQ already: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Answer (score 7):

No, your actual question must be a question, and your answers should address the issues raised in the question. You should not intentionally answer your question in the question body. However, you are totally free to [answer your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463).

This isn't as restrictive as it sounds. If your example solves a reasonable problem, post a question asking for an answer to the problem and post your answer. Just do a check to see if it’s a duplicate.

If you want feedback on your example, figure out some specific questions to post with the code and ask away.

And if you have any future questions about the validity of a question or anything else about Stack Overflow, [meta is free for you to ask away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). :D

Comment: Thank you! I just did exactly that! I posted a question, but included my own solution inside the question ;)

Comment: Please do not post the solution inside the question body. Instead, post it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you think you just want to post a solution to some problem you came up with and will be helpful to others, I would suggest you to write a blog article about it, describing about the issue and solutions. If you don't have or want to have a personal blog, there are free sites where you can post your code/article.

And if anyone has that problem in the future, your blog/article will show up in the web search.
I don't see a reason to posting it on Stack Overflow.

Usually it should be like:
You have an issue/question → ask on Stack Overflow → After getting/gathering an appropriate answer /solution (that includes the solution you found after posting the question) → blog about the issue in detail and the solution to it, pros/cons, and point Stack Overflow as a reference, giving credits to the persons involved.

In short:

1: I wouldn't recommend just posting a self question/answer post. You can get downvotes if you do that. Instead blog it somewhere.

2: In the future if you have a question about Stack Overflow itself you ask it on [META](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the META. Next time I would definitely ask there. But I see no reason to not want to post a question and offer my solution as a part of the question on StockOverflow and let other people offer their solution as well. Because a lot of people are using the site's search engine (and Google too) to see if anyone already has a ready-to-go question/answer before they would post their own. I also think that this site is much more effective than most blogs I came across. But, again, thank you for the META reference. I gave you an "Up" vote just for that! Peace!

Answer (score 1):

This site is for questions only. You will get downvotes if you post examples.

And why would you want to post examples?

Comment: Because I think I might have a solution that would be beneficial to other people when they're doing a search, whether on this site, or in Google.